# How to create insertable view with a sequence id from its origin table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I have a huge point dataset that takes a long time to insert new stuff for users on a different software (QGIS). This table has an id column of type serial

To go around this problem I've created an empty view that has the same exact fields as its original table. At first tried limit 0 but it didn't let it update so I made the view size tiny with a where condition that never gets fulfilled, so i end up with an empty table

Problem now is that when inserting new features, they don't get the id of the original table, and new inserts on the original table need the id because it's the primary key and it also activates other triggers. Sometimes users will need to copy and paste multiple new inserts onto this table

How to make it use the same sequence as the original table and enable people to insert new features on it? I appreciate that this view might not be the best solution but would be open to any better alternative

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview
AS SELECT id,
postcode,
address,
status
FROM mytable WHERE status = 123


CREATE TABLE public.pt (
id serial NOT NULL,
postcode varchar NULL,
address text NULL,
status int2 NOT NULL

CREATE SEQUENCE mytable_seq
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE 36339
MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
START 691524
CACHE 1
NO CYCLE;
```

obv trimmed down many many columns. I'm not sure what's the insert statement

Comment: Please add `create table`, `create sequence` and `insert` statements, so that we can better reproduce your environment.

Comment: Do you need the ID in QGIS? If not, just remove it from the view an from the `instead of` trigger. Or keep it in the view but remove it from the trigger (i.e. the value submitted by the user for the `id` field won't be used)

Comment: @jgh oh damn it worked!! thanks dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sugestion:

Instead of using a view you could create a subset of this large table in another table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_subset AS SELECT id,postcode,address,status
FROM mytable WHERE status = 123;
```

Then the easiest way to manage it would be using triggers. First create a function to take care of the id:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_view_id() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  SELECT nextval('mytable_seq') INTO NEW.id;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

and then attach it to a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_update_view BEFORE INSERT ON mytable_subset
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_view_id();
```

So every time you insert a new record, the id value will be replaced by the `nextval` of your sequence.

```
INSERT INTO mytable_subset(id,postcode,address,status) VALUES (42,'0000','st. one',1);
INSERT INTO mytable_subset (postcode,address,status) VALUES ('0000','st. one',1);

SELECT * FROM mytable_subset;
 id | postcode | address | status 
----+----------+---------+--------
  1 | 0000     | st. one |      1
  2 | 0000     | st. two |      1
(2 Zeilen)
```

Comment: It's not a simple insert statement, that's why I didn't include it here. QGIS uses a cursor and unfortunately these users are not programmers so they need to use this simple interface. While QGIS uses SQL, it does not have the nextval function. Would there be an instead of trigger that can work here?

Comment: Oh now I get it, sorry :) In this case a trigger would be the simplest way. I'll update my answer

Comment: @Luffydude would creating another table instead of a view be an option for you? Instead of `create view w as select * from t` something like `create table w as select * from t`. That would make the usage of triggers much easier. They'll have different values anyway ..

Comment: Actually JGH's solution has worked and it's super simple but your answer also seems like it works so gave you some internet points too :)